# Testing database in django other than django models

Tags: python, mysql, django, unit-testing, automated-tests

I am using mysql-server and MySQLdb for accessing my database. I have not even used django models to accessing the database tables.

Now the problem comes while testing. All the django documentation is talking about the testing using django models. While testing a data, i have to insert data into the database using `cursor.execute()` function then i have to read from that. But this waste out my time.

Also TestCase class run all database query in transaction and my doubt is that, this will be same for mysql-server and myqldb?

I am using MySQLdb since it is faster than django models. Can anyone tell me how can i make the testing simpler ? How can i test the database in django?

Comment: Have you considered using `setUp` and `tearDown` methods of `TestCase` class http://django-testing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_unittests.html#a-couple-neat-features?  Since you're not using Django models for Create and Update, the statement that _django TestCase runs query in transaction_ does not apply.

Comment: yes now i am doing using the both. In setUp i will insert data into tables and in teardown i will delete those data. But these all are carried out on actual database. Is there any way to create test data base in a way django does for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach to setting up your database than overriding `setUp` and `tearDown` methods for `TestCase` is to get out of Django's way by implementing `setUpTestData` instead.

```
from django.db import connections

class BasicTest(TestCase):
     @classmethod
     def setUpTestData(cls):
         alias = 'default'
         cursor = connections[alias].cursor()
         query = 'your query here'
         cursor.execute(query)
```

Django will drop the test database on `tearDownClass`.

For the case you don't have a configuration entry in `settings.py` for your database, you'll need to provide your own `setUp` and `tearDown` for your `TestCase`

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    super(BasicTest, self).setUpClass()
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="toor")
    cls.cursor = db.cursor()

    query = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;'
    cls.cursor.execute(query)

    query = 'USE test;'
    cls.cursor.execute(query)

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    query = 'DROP DATABASE test;'
    cls.cursor.execute(query)
    cls.cursor.close()
```

With this, you can still do your other data operations in `setUpTestData` but the cursor you'll use here is `cls.cursor`.

### References

- [TestCase.setUpTestData](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/testcases.py#L1016)
- [TestCase.tearDownClass](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/testcases.py#L1008)

Comment: But this required to define database back engine, right?

Comment: I haven't use any database backend. I am using mysql-server through MySQLdb in python.

Comment: Yes. Do you mean you don't have a database set in `settings.py`?

Comment: Yeah, i don't have.

Comment: I have created database using mysql shell. Then i have used MySQLdb to connect the database in python. Then the database will be accessed using cursor.execute("your query") function.

Comment: Yes, that'll be the flow except that you'll be explicitly creating your cursor.

Comment: Can i please explain the usage of @classmethod decorator and what is difference between setUp and setUpClass

Comment: `setUp` is an instance method that runs for each `test_*` method while `setUpClass` is a class method  that runs once for the entire `TestCase`. Try it out on this repl https://repl.it/KS60/0

Comment: Also i am not familiar with superClass. sorry, please explain the arguments.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152440/discussion-between-oluwafemi-sule-and-vishnu-m-c).

Comment: I didn't understand the super() function and decorator